# Disable SMTP email address validation

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp

In Ubuntu, how can I configure an SMTP server to **not** check if an email address exists?

Comment: Please include the MTA you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using Postfix?

If you set `local_recipient_maps =` (blank after the "=") in `/usr/share/postfix/main.cf`, it should accept anything on the local domain.

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#local_recipient_maps

Comment: I'm using nothing) will use postfix. thx